# SetFigFontNFSS vs. SetFigFont

Tags: xfig

I'm currently updating a LaTeX document which has about 300 xfig figures. To include the figures into LaTeX, all figures get converted to a `.pstex_t` with `fig2dev -L pstex_t`.

To see if my system compiles the document different, I've recompiled it and made a diff.

I saw that all occurcences of `\SetFigFontNFSS` in those .pstex_t files were replced by `\SetFigFont`.

What does that mean? How do those commands differ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is a standard command, they are just locally defined within the file written by fig2dev, google suggests one is

```
\gdef\SetFigFont#1#2#3#4#5{
\reset@font\fontsize{#1}{#2pt}
\fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}
\selectfont}
```

and the other is

```
\gdef\SetFigFontNFSS#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \reset@font\fontsize{#1}{#2pt}%
  \fontfamily{#3}\fontseries{#4}\fontshape{#5}%
  \selectfont}
```

that is, they are identical apart from some `%` missing from the first have been added to the second. Presumably just a cosmetic name change in different releases of the command combined with a fix for space tokens being added. As it is just defined in each file before it is used, it doesn't really matter what it is called.